# Access to method in the same .factory in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I run the factory, and excecute the function "fn_generarPopupConfirm()" in any controller. 
in this method, I have now created a template. This template has a buton that has an ng-click, which calls an existing function inside the same factory. In my example I have this:

```
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fn_confirmar()">
```

How can I do it to call it ("oElim.fn_confirmar()")?, without needing to define a function in which I define a $scope object, to call the function needed. this function is present in the same factory.

```
controller: function($scope){

    $scope.fn_confirmar=function(){
        oElim.fn_confirmar();
    }
},
```

I need the function to be called directly "oElim.fn_confirmar()" with the ng-click event. it's possible?

this is my factory.

```
.factory('eliminar', function($state,$rootScope,$uibModal,popup_generico) {
  var oElim= {};

  oElim.fn_generarPopupConfirm = function(objeto,array,titulo,contenido) {

  $rootScope.modalInstances.push($uibModal.open({
    template: '<form id="form_popup" class="form-horizontal"><div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title"><button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
    ng-click="fn_confirmar()">
    OK</button></div></form>',
    controller: function($scope){

        $scope.fn_confirmar=function(){
            oElim.fn_confirmar();
        }
    },
    backdrop: 'static'
  }));

}

 oElim.fn_confirmar = function(){
    var index =  oElim.array.indexOf(oElim.objeto);
    oElim.array.splice(index, 1);
    popup_generico.fn_CerrarModal();
 }
    return oElim;
})
```

Comment: I'm surprised the code doesn't work. What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is possible within angular, as the template is a string that will be interpolated within the context of the controller, not the factory.

If you really want to have scope access to the `oElim` factory without injecting it into a controller, you could bind the oElim object directly to the $rootScope, giving you prototypal access to its methods within the template `"$rootScope.oElim.fn_confirmar()"` or equivalently just `"oElim.fn_confirmar()"` from any template you define in your angular app.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's not possible, but you can do the following:

```js
controller: function($scope){
    $scope.fn_confirmar = oElim.fn_confirmar;
},
```

or add the object to $rootScope

```js
.factory('eliminar', function($state,$rootScope,$uibModal,popup_generico) {
  var oElim= {};
 
  $rootScope.oElim = oElim;

  oElim.fn_generarPopupConfirm = function(objeto,array,titulo,contenido) {

  $rootScope.modalInstances.push($uibModal.open({
    template: '<form id="form_popup" class="form-horizontal"><div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title"><button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
    ng-click="oElim.fn_confirmar()">
    OK</button></div></form>',
    controller: Function.prototype, //Just dummy function
    backdrop: 'static'
  }));

}

 oElim.fn_confirmar = function(){
    var index =  oElim.array.indexOf(oElim.objeto);
    oElim.array.splice(index, 1);
    popup_generico.fn_CerrarModal();
 }
    return oElim;
})
```

or better, just used built-in angular event service

```js
.factory('eliminar', function($state,$rootScope,$uibModal,popup_generico) {
  var oElim= {};

  oElim.fn_generarPopupConfirm = function(objeto,array,titulo,contenido) {

  $rootScope.modalInstances.push($uibModal.open({
    template: '<form id="form_popup" class="form-horizontal"><div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title"><button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
    ng-click="$emit('fn_confirmar')">
    OK</button></div></form>',
    controller: Function.prototype, //Just dummy function
    backdrop: 'static'
  }));

}

 oElim.fn_confirmar = function(){
    var index =  oElim.array.indexOf(oElim.objeto);
    oElim.array.splice(index, 1);
    popup_generico.fn_CerrarModal();
 }
 
 $rootScope.$on('fn_confirmar', oElim.fn_confirmar);
    return oElim;
})
```